# BeforeUnload doesn't show Leave dialogue Box when Refresh Page and then Close Browser/Tab

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onbeforeunload

I am working to show message (`Leave Dialogue`) when User close the Browser/Tab.

Until now, when I open the URL in the Browser and do some editing, and then close the Browser/Tab, the `Leave Dialogue` shows up.

The problem occurs, when I `Refresh` the page and then immediately close the Browser, the `Leave Dialogue` doesn't show up.
I have debugged the `BeforeUnload` event, and the event is firing as well as the `Return` value, but still, the Leave Dialogue doesn't show in this scenario.

Here is my code:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
         if (!anIsRefresh && IsViewMode() == false) {
            anIsRefresh = false;
            return e.returnValue = "";
            return "";
         }
      });
```

I am working on Asp.NET MVC.

Another thing: When I `Reload/Refresh` and then instead of closing `Browser/Tab`, click anywhere in DOM and then afterward close the `Browser/Tab`, the `Leave Dialogue` shows up.
For this reason, I have tried to forcefully focus on the field whenever `BeforeUnload` is triggered but still, it doesn't work.